# create map out of property file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4. I want to create a map from my property file as bean so that its loaded in while boot itself. I went through few examples and I understood Environment holds the property file mentioned by @PropertySource. So I wrote something like below, but its not correct throws error in bean creation. Can somebody point me in right direction

property file:

```
 abc=xyz

 bca=ppp

 acs=pkl
```

Property file reader:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:flash.properties")
public class FlashConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        if (env.containsProperty(key)) {
            return env.getProperty(key);
        } else {
            String msg = " flash property not found for the key: " + key;
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(CPContractUtil.getProblemDetail(
                    CPContractExceptionCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, msg));
        }
    }

}
```

stack trace :

```
04:31:11.542 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'getProperty' defined in class path resource [    com/akamai/cpcontract/util/FlashConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No     qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency     annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for     dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.    RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.    jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)     ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-    beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1    .4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4    .RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.    jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.    RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.    4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.    RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.    1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at     least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-    beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.    RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.    jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1    .4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.    RELEASE]
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: could you post the relevant stack trace.

Comment: added in the problem itself

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public static Map<String, Object> allProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> rtn = new HashMap<>();
    if (env instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment) {
        for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : ((ConfigurableEnvironment) env).getPropertySources()) {

            if (propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
                for (String key : ((EnumerablePropertySource) propertySource).getPropertyNames()) {
                    rtn.put(key, propertySource.getProperty(key));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```